# android 8.0 EditText hint content is not in the middle

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext

When the `EditText` not gets the focus, the hint content is not in the middle. Why is this happening? Who can help me?

1. Less than 7.0 its ok
2. in the 7.1 8.0 it unable to display normally

this is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90px">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
        android:background="@color/c_dbdbdb"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
        android:text="年龄"
        android:textColor="@color/c_666666"
        android:textSize="32px"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_new_appointment_age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230px"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="请输入年龄"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minWidth="200px"
        android:textColor="@color/c_333333"
        android:textColorHint="@color/c_999999"
        android:textSize="32px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Define your edit text ellipsize as start and try I think it will help you.

```
android:ellipsize="start"
```

Comment: OKay, I am trying to find another solution when I got I will know you.

Comment: And one more question, How you want to center horizontal or vertical?

Comment: vertical. Less than Android 7.0 its ok

Answer (score 0):

put editText with width and height as wrap content and use

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

inside edit text. it will work.

Comment: look the ui Preiview .the hint not in the top

Comment: I am not do this